# how to use a shortcode parameter without "="

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have this super simple wordpress shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'mytest', 'showMyTest' );
function showMyTest( $atts ) {
    $test =  $atts['test'];
    return $test;
}
```

Usage is this:

```
[mytest test="whatever text"]
```

This works. But since I only use one parameter, I want to simplify this simple code so that I don't have to use "test="

I just want to make it work with this:

```
[mytest "whatever text"]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When using no attribute name, which is what I want, the values (or values) are stored in an array. Accessing them is easy:

```
add_shortcode( 'mytest', 'showMyTest' );
function showMyTest( $atts ) {
    $test =  $atts[0];
    return $test;
}
```

When using this shortcode:

```
[mytest "Hello World"]
```

It will produce "Hello World" (without the quotes)